# Long nil safe method chains

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activesupport

So I know of a few different approaches that I am aware of and I want explore the advantages and disadvantages of the various ways for various criteria which are:

- readability
- performance
- ease of debugging
- OO principles (low coupling and high cohesion)

Explicitly using the try method from active support

```
person.try(:pet).try(:name).try(:upcase)
```

Using a rescue nil

```
person.pet.name.upcase rescue nil
```

Using an && operator chain

```
person && person.pet && person.pet.name && person.pet.name.upcase
```

Monkey patching the Object class, see https://gist.github.com/thegrubbsian/3499234 for the original gist

```
 class Object

      def try_all(*methods)
        values = [self]
        methods.each do |method|
          value = values.last.try(method)
          return nil if value.nil?
          values << value
        end
        values.last
      end

  end

person.try_all(:pet, :name, :upcase)
```

Don't have nil safe code, instead validate the data before you call the code

```
#not a good implementation by any means    
def person_has_pet_with_name? person
  begin 
    return true if !person.pet.name.nil?
  rescue
    return false
  end
end

person.pet.name.upcase if person_has_pet_with_name?(person)
```

Comment: Did my answer help you in any way?

Comment: Please mark answer as question solved, if it answered your question.

Answer (score 4):

My personal opinion about monkey patching in general is do NOT do it unless there is no other way (and even than I think twice if I really want to monkey patch).
Besides Rails already bloated objects a lot. So I'd not suggest custom bloating objects even more.
Why not avoiding to break the law of Demeter by the classic delegator approach:

```
class Person
  attr_accessor :pet
  delegate :name_upcased, to: :pet, 
    prefix: true, allow_nil: true
end

class Pet
  attr_accessor :name
  def name_upcased
    @name.upcase if @name
  end
end

@person.try :pet_name_upcased
```

You can also read about the law of Demeter at [Do not break the law of Demeter!](http://chris-on-rails.blogspot.de/2014/08/do-not-break-law-of-demeter.html) and [Module#delegate](http://apidock.com/rails/Module/delegate).
At least I would not stick to [Object#try](http://apidock.com/rails/Object/try) as long as a simple condition solves it, because looking at the source of 'try' it is more costly than the condition.

Answer (score 0):

I'd avoid the long call chains as they're a clear violation of the [Law of Demeter](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Law_of_Demeter):

```
person.try(:pet).try(:name).try(:upcase)
```

If you'd want to test code like that and somehow stub person, your tests will become extremely complex. I would suggest a solution like the following, where the complexity of this chain is divided between the classes involved. This is the Object-Oriented way. Here, none of the classes knows too much about the other.

```
class Person
  def upcased_pet_name
    pet.try(:upcased_name)
  end
end

class Pet
  def upcased_name
    name.try(:upcase)
  end
end

# Simple method call. nil checks are handled elsewhere
person.try(:upcased_pet_name)
```

In your tests, it's now a lot easier to stub `person`, and your code is a lot easier to read.

Comment: I read  your blog post about Object#try afterwards. Nice. But Object#try is more costly than a simple condition. That is why I'm not a big fan of it. So maybe not overusing it, if a condition also can be hidden?

Comment: The `if` approach you did also works very nicely, partly because it also works in plain Ruby. It could be a good refactoring to my code.

Answer (score 0):

The problem with the Law of Demeter is that your classes know too much about each other, making them more tightly coupled, which in turn makes them more buggy and harder to test.

In my experience, the most frequent violations of the Law of Demeter are in views. Since you are trying to capitalise the name, I'm guessing that's the case here. Soooo....

Can you use a view helper? Sorry, not much good at Rails, so this is pseudocodish:

```
def upcased_name(entity_with_name)
    if entity_with_name != nil
      entity_with_name.name.try(:upcase)
    end
end
```

Then in your view, you just call

```
<% upcased_name(person.pet) %>
```

You can test the `upcased_pet_name` by injecting different values to the viewhelper.

Now:

- Your view knows only that is has access to a 'Person', and access to a  viewhelper called `upcased_name`.
- Your `Person` model knows only that it has a `Pet` method.
- Your viewhelper knows only that it can receive an entity with a name method, or a `nil`.

Boom! Your classes know only about their friends, and nothing about the friends of their friends.

Comment: Your code includes some issues. First of all I wouldn't put it into a helper, because it is not a view concern only. Then <%= upcased_name(person.pet) %> instead of <% upcased_name(person.pet) %> and what if the person is nil? Then entity_with_name.name.try(:upcase) if entity_with_name.nil? instead of the stiffy if entity_with_name != nil and at least the delegator approach works smoother than the try thingi, which is more costly and refers more to the trial & error expression.