# How to use delegate with try in Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I have a relation within my application where one `Client` has `Address` which belongs to one `Province`.

Now I want to put the province name near the client data, so I created a method in client.rb:

```
def province_name
  try(:address).try(:province).try(:name)
end
```

The problem is that not every client has joined address. This method works but it looks ugly. Is it possible to write in a better way, maybe using `delegate` method?

Comment: Looks fine to me. The ugliness is hidden inside of a method.

Comment: in `address` u can use `delegate :name, to: :province` and in access it by `address.name`

Comment: [check this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25758830/long-nil-safe-method-chains) and [this](http://simonecarletti.com/blog/2009/12/inside-ruby-on-rails-delegate/)

Comment: Guys I did it with 2 delegates:

delegate :province_name, to: :address, allow_nil: true in client.rb

and

delegate :name, to: :province, prefix: true in addres.rb

everything works fine. What do you think? I like this solution.

Answer (score 0):

We've achieved something similar before:

```
#app/models/client.rb
class Client < ActiveRecord::Base
   has_one :address
end

#app/models/address.rb
class Address < ActiveRecord::Base
   belongs_to :province
   delegate :name, to: :province
end

#app/models/province.rb
class Province < ActiveRecord::Base
   has_many :addresses
   def name
      self[:name] ||= province
   end

   def province
     self[:province] ||= address
   end
end
```

You may wish to refactor the above code - but it works perfectly for us:

```
#app/models/user.rb
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
   has_one :profile, inverse_of :user
   delegate :name, to: :profile
end

#app/models/profile.rb
class Profile < ActiveRecord::Base
   belongs_to :user, inverse_of :profile
   def name
        self[:name] ||= user.email
   end
end
```